# How do I access the Tango's depth information while using OpenCV functions

Tags: android, opencv, google-project-tango

I'm trying to use OpenCV in a Tango app to perform some CV tasks. I also need the Tango's depth information for some other stuff, but using OpenCV's camera object blocks the `onXyzIjAvailable()` method from being called. As a workaround I'm trying to use a TangoCameraView object which gives me access to the Tango's point cloud data, but not the OpenCV functions.

So is there any way to convert the Tango's camera data to a Mat format or something OpenCV can understand? Is there another way to use OpenCV with the Tango which I haven't though of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no direct translation between Tango API to openCV. But the general strategy for working with Tango callback is to copy data from callback thread to render/update thread, and let the update loop to do the heavy lifting(conversion, processing, etc)

Comment: I just came across the same problem as OP and was wondering if you could provide a little more context to your question? Mainly on how to copy data from the callback thread. Thank you!